# Why the non-static reference error while there is no static defined?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I don't understand why the error "non-static method getLoginPage() cannot be referenced from a static context" here!? There is nothing static here! Seems trivial but I am not sure what I'm missing.

**EDIT:**
I understand that by instantiating TestFramework I can get rid of the error but as recommended, I'm trying to avoid instantiating objects in my unit tests and pass the object creation to my framework if needed. On the other hand making getLoginPage() in TestFramework static, creates a whole bunch of similar errors in my TestFramework class!

**Class Tests.java:**

```
public class Tests {

@Test
public void User_Can_Login(){
    String username = "Jake";
    String password = "Jake";
    TestFramework.getLoginPage().Login(username, password);
    assertTrue(TestFramework.getLoginPage().CheckIfLoggedIn(username));
}
```

**Class TestFramework.Java:**

```
public class TestFramework {

private LoginPage loginPage;

public LoginPage getLoginPage() {
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
    PageFactory.initElements(Browser.getDriver(), loginPage);
    return loginPage;
}

public class LoginPage {

    String Url = "http://localhost:8080";
    String welcomeMsg = "Welcome";

    public void Login(String username, String password) {
        Browser.Goto(Url);
        Browser.Input(username,password);
        Browser.Submit();
    }
    public boolean CheckIfLoggedIn(String user){
        return Browser.getTextByxpath("/html/body/header/div/p").contains(welcomeMsg + " " + user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you have no instance of TestFramework...

Comment: `getLoginPage()` method is not static. So you cant call like `TestFramework.getLoginPage()`. You need to create object `new TestFramework().getLoginPage();`

Comment: On a side note, you may wish to refer to Java naming conventions i.e. method names starting with lower case, no underscores etc

Comment: @JamesB right on! coming back to Java after a while I had forgotten the naming convention, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TestFramework.getLoginPage().Login(username, password);
```

There in that line `TestFramework`  is not an instance and compiler assuming it as a static type. Create an instance of `TestFramework` and call the method.

You might need

```
TestFramework tfWork = new TestFramework();
tfwork.getLoginPage().Login(username, password);
assertTrue(tfWork.getLoginPage().CheckIfLoggedIn(username));
```

Comment: That seems to be the case but I'm trying to refrain from instantiating objects in my test class as it's not recommended. Does that mean I will need to make everything in my framework static instead to be able to call it from my unit test?

Comment: @SabaAhang That's not a good idea to make everything static. And remember that the varaibles and methods used in side a static method also be static. Do not do that. use instances.

Answer (score 1):

What's `TestFramework` if not a static context (it's a class, not an instance).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the method using class name instead of instance.

```
TestFramework.getLoginPage().Login(username, password);
```

insted do it like this

```
new TestFramework().getLoginPage().Login(username, password);
```